# How to find every occurrence of a word and append some text to it?

Tags: replace

I have to find a word and append some other text to in in Vim:
for instance I have to append to every occurrence of the word "`public_html`" the text "`/Text-Analysis-Tool`" to obtain "`public_html/Text-Analysis-Tool`".

I've tried using the following command:

```
:%s/public_html/public_html/Text-Analysis-Tool/gg
```

But is is producing the error `E488: trailing characters`.

Can someone please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: You can use another separator character, instead of `/`. For instance, `:%s#public_html#public_html/Text-Analysis-Tool#gg`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that Vim is interpreting the `/` character in your *replacement* as a delimiter character used by the `:substitute` command. The syntax of the `:s` command is as follows:

```
:[range]s/pattern/replacement/flags
```

The above syntax uses the `/` character to delimit *pattern*, *replacement*, and *flags*; however, some other characters (usually punctuation or symbols) can be used.

To fix your problem, you have two options.

### Option 1

Escape any `/` characters in your *pattern* and *replacement* using `\`:

```
:%s/public_html/public_html\/Text-Analysis-Tool/gg
```

### Option 2

Use a different delimiter character. To avoid escaping, choose one that does not appear in your *pattern* or *replacement*. For this case, let's use `#`:

```
:%s#public_html#public_html/Text-Analysis-Tool#gg
```

### Bonus

Appending to a search pattern is a special situation where we can use some features that are fairly unique to Vim's flavour of regex. Vim has zero-width anchors `\zs` and `\ze` that define the start and end (respectively) of the part of your pattern that you want to match. Anything before `\zs` or after `\ze` in your *pattern* will not be part of the patch, and thus will remain unaffected by *replacement*.

Instead of repeating the *pattern* part in the *replacement*, we can define the start of the match as the end of the pattern. Below, I'll continue with the technique from **Option 2** to avoid escaping.

```
:%s#public_html\zs#/Text-Analysis-Tool#gg
```

You can look at it like this: we're replacing an empty string that follows `public_html` with `/Text-Analysis-Tool`.

Note that omitting either of these zero-width anchors is like having `\zs` at the start of the pattern and/or `\ze` at the end of the pattern.

---

#### Side note

I noticed you're using `gg` for your *flags*. This is identical to not using any `g` in your *flags* at all -- each `g` inverts the *global* behaviour. If this wasn't merely a typo, I suspect that you might have the `'gdefault'` option enabled. This has the effect that using `g` will make the substitution *not* global, and no `g` in *flags* (or `gg`) will make it global.

Turning this option off (rather, not turning it on, as it's off by default) will let you use a single `g` for the global behaviour.

Comment: Even more bonus: Use `&` to replace with the entire match. e.g. `:%s#public_html#&/Text-Analysis-Tool#`. For more help see `:h /\0`